# Как прижать картинку внутри контейнера к правой части? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Есть код

```html
<div class="bg-light w-100">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><img class="d-block float-right" src="https://nataska-legavyh.ru/wp-content/themes/nataskalegavyh/img/header_dog.png"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Дело в том, что картинку хочу прижать прям к самой правой части, но контейнер видимо не позволяет и оставляет небольшой зазор. Отметил на картинке. Подскажите, как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Убрать padding и margin у контейнера и картинки - а вообще-то, через F12 и Ctrl+Shift+C посмотреть, что и где и к чему относится и то и убрать.

Answer (score 0):

1. Возможно изображение не корректное
2. Pading у container
3. Можно пофиксить отрицательными margin